# SQL: Need help in forming one query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need one help in forming a query.
From the table1, for one field which is holding an sum amount contains the numbers like "10 , -10" etc but before inserting into table2. I have to change it to a format such as "000000010+ or 000000010-" respectively as:

```
Table1 => Required Format in Table2
10     => 000000010+
-10    => 000000010-
```

Comment: how many zeors you want to prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH DATA(STR) AS(
select '-10' from dual
)
select 
CASE WHEN INSTR(STR,'-')=1 THEN
to_char(-STR,'00000000')||'-'
ELSE
to_char(STR,'00000000')||'+'
END FORMAT
from DATA;
```